# process a dataframe pulled from SQL with pandas and list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I am trying to take a pandas dataframe fed from SQL, filter the locations (Shortcut Dimension 1 Code), and calculate the amount - credits for each.

The below code is giving me the following error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

I would appreciate any advice or help on making it work :|

```
inv = inv_line_query()
crmemo = cr_memo_line_query()


def mtd_actual(invoices=inv, creds=crmemo, location=['*']):
    mtd_actual_dict = {}
    invoices = invoices[invoices['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'].isin(location)]
    creds = creds[creds['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'].isin(location)]
    for loc in location:
        amt = [round(x, 2) for x in invoices['Amount'] if invoices['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'] == loc]
        cred = [round(x, 2) for x in creds['Amount'] if creds['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'] == loc]
        mtd_actual_dict[loc] = round(sum(amt) - sum(cred), 2)
    return mtd_actual_dict


print(mtd_actual(inv, crmemo, ['AB', 'BC', 'ONT']))
```

Comment: You've approached this problem in the wrong way. `location=['*']` is a mutable default argument (google that, or "python least astonishment") and then you're iterating. If I had to guess, you're coming from Java? You shouldn't be iterating here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dataframe works in Columnar structure, therefore the for loop while calculating `amt` and `cred` cannot iterate the way you mentioned.

Changing your code like this would work out easily.

```py
inv = inv_line_query()
crmemo = cr_memo_line_query()

def mtd_actual(invoices=inv, creds=crmemo, location=None):
    mtd_actual_dict = {}
    invoices = invoices[invoices['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'].isin(location)]
    creds = creds[creds['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'].isin(location)]
    for loc in location:
        amt = invoices[invoices['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'] == loc]['Amount'].sum()
        cred = creds[creds['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'] == loc]['Amount'].sum()
        mtd_actual_dict[loc] = round((amt - cred), 2)
    return mtd_actual_dict


print(mtd_actual(inv, crmemo, ['AB', 'BC', 'ONT']))
```

Also, seems like you need location based values in a dictionary. Instead of iterating on location, you can also leverage pandas Dataframe features.
**This solution will scale efficiently on big list of location whereas previous solution might cause computation cost.**

```py
def mtd_actual(invoices=inv, creds=crmemo, location=None):
    # filter values based on location
    invoices = invoices[invoices['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'].isin(location)]
    creds = creds[creds['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'].isin(location)]

    # group on location and sum the amount
    inv_grp = invoices.groupby('Shortcut Dimension 1 Code').agg({"Amount" : "sum"}).reset_index()
    cred_grp = creds.groupby('Shortcut Dimension 1 Code').agg({"Amount" : "sum"}).reset_index()

    # merge these two dataframes, make sure this needs to be an outer join
    final = inv_grp.merge(cred_grp, 
                          on='Shortcut Dimension 1 Code', 
                          suffix=("", "_"),
                          how="outer")

    # fill nan values with 0
    final[["Amount", "Amount_"]] = final[["Amount", "Amount_"]].fillna(0)
    final["diff"] = round(final['Amount'] - final['Amount_'], 2)

    return final[["Shortcut Dimension 1 Code", "diff"]].to_dict("record")
```

Comment: I am extremely grateful for your answer. I am new to pandas so the biggest help is understanding the better way of doing it!

Answer (score 1):

You're giving invoices['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'].isin(location) and creds['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'].isin(location) which are both a list of booleans to filter the Dataframe but to filter you should provide a list of index and not a list of booleans.

I would try transforming these lists in index of the dataframe, something like this:

changing this part in your code:

```
 invoices = invoices[invoices['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'].isin(location)]
 creds = creds[creds['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'].isin(location)]
```

to this:

```
    list_of_bools_invoices = invoices['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'].isin(location)
    list_of_index_invoices = [index_of_row for index_of_row,bool in enumerate(list_of_bools_invoices) if bool]
    invoices = invoices[list_of_index_invoices]

    list_of_bools_creds = creds['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'].isin(location)
    list_of_index_creds = [index_of_row for index_of_row,bool in enumerate(list_of_bools_creds) if bool]
    creds = creds[list_of_index_creds]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider processing calculations with pandas Series operations:

```
...
    amt = invoices[invoices['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'] == loc]['Amount'].round(2) 
    cred = creds[creds['Shortcut Dimension 1 Code'] == loc]['Amount'].round(2)

    mtd_actual_dict[loc] = (amt.sum() - cred.sum()).round(2)
return mtd_actual_dict
```